# MQ fix pack upgrade issues

Tags: ibm-mq

I have MQ V8.0.0.2 installed in my system and I am applying the fix pack to upgrade it to 8.0.0.5 using the silent install method. It runs successfully and finishes but `dspmqver` still says the version as 8.0.0.2.

It is on a Windows 7 machine 64 bit. The exe file I am using to apply the fix pack is `WS-MQ-8.0.0-FP0005.exe`.

I am not getting any errors in the command prompt. I followed the installation instructions IBM suggested while downloading the fix pack. I stopped the MQ manager and then ran the command WS-MQ-8.0.0-FP0005.exe -f silent_install.resp 
I gave the response file name along with its path. But its still not working.

**Update**
On a multi-installation setup the update was being applied properly but to a different installation.  To fix the problem, run `amqicsdn.exe` as described in [*Applying maintenance level updates on IBM MQ servers*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008090_.htm) in the Windows maintenance Tasks section of the Knowledge Center.

```
amqicsdn MQPINSTALLATIONNAME=name MQPSILENT=1
```

This invocation sets a pointer to the installation that is to be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response file tells the installer what to do and what to install.  Depending on what is set there, what you are seeing is what would be expected.

Specifically, the `MQPREBOOT` and `MQPINUSEOK` parms tell the installer whether or not to continue if a file it needs to update is in use. There are two likely outcomes here.

1) The maintenance was applied correctly but because files were in use it will not show up until after a reboot.
2) The `MQPINUSEOK` parm told the installer to bail out if the files were in use.

On Windows, even though the QMgr is stopped, the service continues running.  Depending on the `MQPINUSEOK` setting that would either cause the install to fail or to complete pending a reboot.

It is worth noting that installing *anything* on Windows requires a couple of reboots.  The very first thing before running the install or upgrade is to reboot.  That ensures that the registry is saved at the current values.  It also ensures that if someone else's app has gone rogue with a memory leak or other issue, it gets cleared before your MQ install proceeds.

After the install, reboot again to ensure the registry with the new MQ settings is saved.  That's because if the server crashes, you want the last known good registry entry to be the one with your install or upgrade reflected in it.  That also ensures the services still start as expected.

Finally, I'm unsure what "the installation instructions IBM suggested while downloading the fix pack" are but the official instructions are in the Knowledge Center section [*Windows: Applying maintenance level upgrades on IBM MQ servers*](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008090_.htm). Among the other information you will find there is that the location for the installation log is either specified in the response file or defaults to `amqicsdn.txt` in your TEMP directory (`%TEMP%`).

Comment: Hey T.Rob, I am checking the version using the dspmqver command itself. My version is 8.0.0.2 it says :( It's not upgrading the version!

Comment: Updated the question and answer based on most recent comments. All relevant info needs to be in the Q&A so I've deleted my old comments. Suggest you do the same.  If the answer solves the problem, please vote and accept.  If not, please provide details fromt he install log.

Comment: Rob, I see the Change IBM WebSphere MQ (fix pack 8.0.0.5 files) Installation.exe file in my directory "C:\Program Files\IBM\source\WebSphere MQ 8.0.0.5\_IBM WebSphere MQ (fix pack 8.0.0.5 files)_installation" but when I open the MQ Explorer it still says the version is 8.0.0.2 I am just confused if it got installed or not. I even rebooted my system and the version still stays the same!

Comment: I fixed it by running the amqicsdn.exe file present in one of the folder locations. Thanks Rob for the help!

Comment: Hi @user3845894 if T.Rob's answer helped you fix your problem and so would help others who encounter the same problem could you accept the answer so it is the answer other people see? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more details on what to do when someone answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the Message Queue Manager and then run the installation command again (after modifying the silent response file). If you still face this issue, check if you have a "C:\Program Files\IBM\source\WebSphere MQ 8.0.0.5" folder created and then run the "amqicsdn.exe" file. That should resolve your issue!

Comment: I've updated the question to capture detail of the solution.